# Can sequential pattern mining be called an unsupervised learning method?

Tags: data-mining, unsupervised-learning

[Sequential pattern mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_Pattern_Mining) finds patterns in unlabeled data. So I assume its an unsupervised learning algorithm. But most references to pattern mining never mention the learning part. Why? Can sequential pattern mining be called an unsupervised learning method?

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_machine_learning_algorithms) Wikipedia articles lists the Apriori algorithm as an unsupervised method, but no citations.

Comment: Outside of machine learning, people avoid the "learning" term to avoid confusion with supervised learning methods. It is debatable how much "learning" is involved when you do not have examples to learn from.

Comment: Yes, its definitely not supervised machine learning. But since it finds structure (patterns) in unlabeled data, why can't it be called an unsupervised method?

Comment: It can be called. It's just that outside of the machine learning domain, people don't bother to call every unsupervised method "unsupervised learning". It's unsupervised, but there is not a lot "learning" going on, unless you call any use of statistics "learning".